# Mounting volume for two nodes in minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, persistent-volumes

I am [mounting a filesystem](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/mount/) on minikube:

```
minikube mount /var/files/:/usr/share/ -p multinode-demo
```

But I found two complications:

- My cluster has two nodes. The pods in the first node are able to access the host files at `/var/files/`, but the pods in the second node are not. What can be the reason for that?
- I have to mount the directory before the pods have been created. If I `apply` my deployment first, and then do the `mount`, the pods never get the filesystem. Is Kubernetes not able to apply the mounting later, over an existing deployment that required it?

Comment: Which version of minikube and K8s are you using?

Comment: `minikube-linux-amd64 version`
minikube version: v1.23.2
commit: 0a0ad764652082477c00d51d2475284b5d39ceed

Comment: `kubectl version --client=true`
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"23", GitVersion:"v1.23.1", GitCommit:"86ec240af8cbd1b60bcc4c03c20da9b98005b92e", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-12-16T11:41:01Z", GoVersion:"go1.17.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Comment: In my opinion, your problem is related to these GitHub issues: [Storage provisioner broken for multinode mode](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/12165#issuecomment-895104495) & [hostPath permissions wrong on multi node](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/11765#issuecomment-868965821). Instead, I would suggest using e.g. NFS mounts as described [here](https://paysonwallach.com/garden/minikube-nfs-mounts/index.html).

Comment: It could be a valid alternative, thanks

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments section, I believe your problem is related to the following GitHub issues: [Storage provisioner broken for multinode mode](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/12165#issuecomment-895104495) and [hostPath permissions wrong on multi node](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/11765#issuecomment-868965821).

In my opinion, you might be interested in using NFS mounts instead, and I'll briefly describe this approach to illustrate how it works.

---

First we need to install the NFS Server and create the NFS export directory on our host:
**NOTE:** I'm using Debian 10 and your commands may be different depending on your Linux distribution.

```
$ sudo apt install nfs-kernel-server -y

$ sudo mkdir -p /mnt/nfs_share && sudo chown -R nobody:nogroup /mnt/nfs_share/
```

Then, grant permissions for accessing the NFS server and export the NFS share directory:

```
$ cat /etc/exports 
/mnt/nfs_share  *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash,insecure)

$ sudo exportfs -a && sudo systemctl restart nfs-kernel-server
```

We can use the `exportfs -v` command to display the current export list:

```
$ sudo exportfs -v
/mnt/nfs_share  <world>(rw,wdelay,insecure,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,sec=sys,rw,insecure,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)
```

Now it's time to create a minikube cluster:

```
$ minikube start --nodes 2

$ kubectl get nodes
NAME           STATUS   ROLES                 VERSION
minikube       Ready    control-plane,master  v1.23.1
minikube-m02   Ready    <none>                v1.23.1
```

Please note, we're going to use the `standard` [StorageClass](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/):

```
$ kubectl get storageclass
NAME                 PROVISIONER                RECLAIMPOLICY   VOLUMEBINDINGMODE   ALLOWVOLUMEEXPANSION   
standard (default)   k8s.io/minikube-hostpath   Delete          Immediate           false
```

Additionally, we need to find the Minikube gateway address:

```
$ minikube ssh
docker@minikube:~$ ip r | grep default
default via 192.168.49.1 dev eth0
```

Let's create `PersistentVolume` and `PersistentVolumeClaim` which will use the NFS share:
**NOTE:** The address `192.168.49.1` is the Minikube gateway.

```
$ cat pv.yaml 
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nfs-volume
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: standard
  nfs:
    server: 192.168.49.1
    path: "/mnt/nfs_share"

$ kubectl apply -f pv.yaml 
persistentvolume/nfs-volume created

$ cat pvc.yaml 
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nfs-claim
  namespace: default
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
      
$ kubectl apply -f pvc.yaml 
persistentvolumeclaim/nfs-claim created


$ kubectl get pv,pvc
NAME                          CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM               STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
persistentvolume/nfs-volume   1Gi        RWX            Retain           Bound    default/nfs-claim   standard                71s

NAME                              STATUS   VOLUME       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
persistentvolumeclaim/nfs-claim   Bound    nfs-volume   1Gi        RWX            standard       56s
```

Now we can use the NFS PersistentVolume - to test if it works properly I've created `app-1` and `app-2` Deployments:
**NOTE:** The `app-1` will be deployed on different node than `app-2` (I've specified `nodeName` in the PodSpec).

```
$ cat app-1.yaml 
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: app-1
  name: app-1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app-1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app-1
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
        volumeMounts:
        - name: app-share
          mountPath: /mnt/app-share
      nodeName: minikube 
      volumes:
      - name: app-share
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: nfs-claim
          

$ kubectl apply -f app-1.yaml 
deployment.apps/app-1 created

$ cat app-2.yaml 
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: app-2
  name: app-2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app-2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app-2
    spec:
      nodeName: minikube
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
        volumeMounts:
        - name: app-share
          mountPath: /mnt/app-share
      nodeName: minikube-m02 
      volumes:
      - name: app-share
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: nfs-claim


$ kubectl apply -f app-2.yaml 
deployment.apps/app-2 created


$ kubectl get deploy,pods -o wide
NAME                    READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE     CONTAINERS   IMAGES   SELECTOR
deployment.apps/app-1   1/1     1            1           24s     nginx        nginx    app=app-1
deployment.apps/app-2   1/1     1            1           21s     nginx        nginx    app=app-2

NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     NODE           
pod/app-1-7874b8d7b6-p9cb6   1/1     Running   0          23s     minikube       
pod/app-2-fddd84869-fjkrw    1/1     Running   0          21s     minikube-m02
```

To verify that our NFS share works as expected, we can create a file in the `app-1` and then check that we can see that file in the `app-2` and on the host:

*app-1:*

```
$ kubectl exec -it app-1-7874b8d7b6-p9cb6 -- bash
root@app-1-7874b8d7b6-p9cb6:/# df -h | grep "app-share"
192.168.49.1:/mnt/nfs_share  9.7G  7.0G  2.2G  77% /mnt/app-share
root@app-1-7874b8d7b6-p9cb6:/# touch /mnt/app-share/app-1 && echo "Hello from the app-1" > /mnt/app-share/app-1
root@app-1-7874b8d7b6-p9cb6:/# exit
exit
```

*app-2:*

```
$ kubectl exec -it app-2-fddd84869-fjkrw -- ls /mnt/app-share
app-1

$ kubectl exec -it app-2-fddd84869-fjkrw -- cat /mnt/app-share/app-1
Hello from the app-1
```

*host:*

```
$ ls /mnt/nfs_share/
app-1

$ cat /mnt/nfs_share/app-1 
Hello from the app-1
```

Comment: It does not solve the initial question per se, but it is very useful. Thanks for sharing