# Minikube multi-node cluster mounting host machine filesystem to all the nodes

Tags: kubernetes, filesystems, minikube, mount, kubernetes-cluster

I am creating a Minikube multi-node kubernetes cluster with 2 nodes mounting the **$HOME/Minikube/mount** directory from the host filesystem to the **data** directory in the cluster nodes.

I used the following command to achieve this,

```
minikube start --nodes 2 --cpus 2 --memory 2048 --disk-size 10g --mount-string $HOME/Minikube/mount:/data --mount --namespace test -p multi-node
```

> Minikube version: 1.28.0
> Kubernetes client version: v1.26.0
> Kubernetes server version: v1.24.3

Expectation was to find the **/data** directory in both nodes (**multi-node(control-plane)** and **multi-node-m02**) mount to the **$HOME/Minikube/mount** directory of the host filesystem.

But when i ssh to the Minikube nodes i only see the **/data** directory mount in the **multi-node** which functions as the kubernetes control plane node. Local filesystem directory is not mount to both nodes.

```
minikube ssh -n multi-node
ls -la /data/
```

> $ ls -la /data/
> total 0

```
minikube ssh -n multi-node-m02
ls -la /data/
```

> $ ls -la /data
> ls: cannot access '/data': No such file or directory

Is there some way to achieve this requirement of mounting a local filesystem directory to all the nodes in a multi-node Minikube k8s cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As they mentioned in this [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/13397), using `minikube start --mount` has some issues when mounting the files. Try using the  `minikube mount string`.

If the issue still persists the issue is with the storage provisioner broken for multinode mode. For this issue minikube has recently added a [local path provisioner](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/pull/15062), adding it to the default storage class resolves your issue.

Comment: I tried both ***mount*** option and ***storage-provisioner-rancher*** option both didn't work.
Behaviour is same with "mount" option as explained above.
I got the following error while trying to enable the ***storage-provisioner-rancher*** addon,
```Exiting due to MK_ADDON_ENABLE: run callbacks: storage-provisioner-rancher is not a valid addon```

Comment: Attaching a [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70878064/mounting-volume-for-two-nodes-in-minikube), can you try it and let me know if this works.